# How can I use the rails helper "distance_of_time_in_words" in plain old ruby (non-rails)

Tags: ruby, datetime, date, time, helper

Rails has an helper which converts distance of time in words using distance_of_time_in_words

What do I need to include if I am just using ruby at the irb prompt to get this function?

I tried `require 'action_view'` but it didn't help.

I also tried `require 'active_support/core_ext'` but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

This should work:

`require 'action_view'`

`include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper`

Both of these need to be done for a couple of reasons.  First, you need to require the library, so that its modules and methods are available to be called. This is why you need to do `require 'action_view'`.

Second, since `distance_of_time_in_words` is module, which does not stand on its own, it needs to be included in class. You can then access it by calling `distance_of_time_in_words` on an instance of that class.

When you are in the console, you already have an instance of the `Object` class running.  You can verify this by calling `self` in the irb console.  When you call `include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper`, you are including those methods for any instance of the `Object` class. Since that is the implicit receiver of the irb console, you can then just save `distance_of_time_in_words` right on the console and get what you want!

Comment: I'm getting like `"translation missing: en.datetime.distance_in_words.x_months"` when trying to use such helper. Am I missing something?

Comment: @mlt I think you're missing that entry from your I18n file in `config/`, but if that doesn't work open up a question and I'll try to help.