# Distance of time in words?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime, time

I'm trying to use the helper distance_of_time_in_words, it's working fine, but the number of days is not accurate.

I have in my table:

```
t.datetime "start"
t.datetime "end"
```

And I'm using:

```
<%= distance_of_time_in_words(Time.now, @promotion.end) %>
```

The thing is, my promotion has an end for tomorrow, but in my view it still says "4 days till end" ...

What can be wrong?

Comment: @TheChamp I'd assumed it's the built-in one.

Comment: [distance_of_time_in_words](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words) and including it http://stackoverflow.com/a/9573793/1183537

Comment: Without seeing what is returned by `Time.now` (your system clock could be off) and `@promotion.end`, there is very little advice anyone can offer you.

Comment: Sorry guys, my WIFI was broken.

Comment: Today it will show 5 days instead of 4...something's weird! @DaveNewton

Comment: @TheChamp It's the built in one

Comment: Without knowing what you're looking at it's 100% impossible to help, surely you understand that. The function itself works perfectly fine. You have to show an example of a failure mode, e.g., show the data you're using.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that distance_of_time_in_words have calculated days incorrectly in your case. For instance, you wouldn't expect it to count 41 hours as still 1 day, but it does:

```
helper.distance_of_time_in_words(41.hours+ 59.minutes+29.seconds)
=> "1 day"
```

See the fancy rounding principles it uses, here:
http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/distance_of_time_in_words

See my email to Rails core, regarding this behavior, here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/rubyonrails-core/distance_of_time_in_words/rubyonrails-core/VnfsO0TNTOI/-EKjN6Egr6cJ