# Rails 5 include helper in class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

We are migrating from Rails 4.2 to 5.2. The following code works fine in 4.2 but not in 5

```
require 'action_view'

module OurModule
  class CheckReport
    include ActionView::Helpers::DateHelper

    def self.our_method
      start_time = Time.current
      LOGGER.info "OurModule::CheckReport.our_method finished in #{distance_of_time_in_words(start_time, Time.current)}"
    end
  end
end
```

But in Rails 5 we are getting:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `distance_of_time_in_words' for OurModule::CheckReport:Class
```

This seems to be because these are class methods and not instance methods.

So, why did it work in Rails 4 (same ruby version - 2.4.9) and what can we do to fix it (apart from making all these cases instance methods?)

Comment: I think this question had answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573628/how-can-i-use-the-rails-helper-distance-of-time-in-words-in-plain-old-ruby-no/9573793

Comment: This may help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489641/using-helpers-in-model-how-do-i-include-helper-dependencies/7593347#answer-489910

Comment: Thanks but neither of those questions addresses either question (why the code above works perfectly in Rails 4 and what to do in Rails 5). The first question/answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573628/how-can-i-use-the-rails-helper-distance-of-time-in-words-in-plain-old-ruby-no/9573793) is where I got the above code. The second question/answer basically (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489641/using-helpers-in-model-how-do-i-include-helper-dependencies/7593347#answer-489910) says don't 'include' but call the helpers directly, which is a totally different way of doing things.

Comment: @phil Did you happen to find a solution for your problem? I just upgraded my rails to 5.2 as well and all the helper methods in the views are failing, the error `NoMethodError - undefined method for #<#<Class:0x00007f998a8869b0>:0x00007f998a87da68>`

Comment: @KedarnagMukanahallipatna - I posted an answer. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as some people are coming here to find the answer, here is what I did:

```
require 'action_view'

module OurModule
  class CheckReport

    def self.our_method
      start_time = Time.current
      LOGGER.info "OurModule::CheckReport.our_method finished in #{ActionController::Base.helpers.distance_of_time_in_words(start_time, Time.current)}"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks!, here's what I did. I added the helper call in the controller that renders it something like `helper OurModule`. I am not sure if what I have done is good practice, I'll try what you have done.